# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: loginMutation is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

below is my code

```
export const LOG_USER_IN = gql`
  mutation LogUserIn($token: String!) {
    logUserIn(token: $token) @client
  }
`;


export default () => {
  const loginMutation = useMutation(LOG_USER_IN)

  const success = authObj => {
    const { response } = authObj;
    if (response["access_token"]) {
      axios({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/graphql",
        method: "post",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer` },
        data: {
          query: print(SOCIAL_AUTH),
          variables: {
            accessToken: response["access_token"],
            provider: "kakao"
          }
        }
      }).then(result => {
        const {
          data: {
            socialAuth: { social, token }
          }
        } = result.data;
        if (social) {
          loginMutation({
            variables: { token }
          });
        } else {
          alert("error");
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("error");
    }
  };
```

it show me error like that "LoginPresenter.js:34 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: loginMutation is not a function"

i use react-apollo-hooks": "^0.5.0",
somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `useMutation` hook incorrectly.

Check out the docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/mutations/#what-is-the-usemutation-hook

You have to do it this way

```
const [loginMutation, {data}] = useMutation(LOG_USER_IN)
```